# Solving trigonometric equation $\sin\left(0.001-t\right)= \frac12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I solve this equation:

$$\sin\left(0.001-t\right)= \frac12$$

Thank you for your help.

P.s. I know that the solution of:

$$\sin\left(t\right)= \frac12$$

is:

$$t=\frac\pi6 +2\pi n,\qquad t=\frac{5\pi}6 +2\pi n$$

Comment: I don't get it? Hasn't the OP solved the problem himself/herself?

Comment: What is the question here? Just put in the first part $\;0.001-t\;$ equal to the "t" in the second part...it is already solved!

Comment: I am amazed how this question has got 2 upvotes !

Answer (score 2):

Solving, for $t$:

$$\sin(\text{a}-t)=\frac{1}{2}$$

When we take the inverse sine of both sides we get two different solutions, where $n_1\space\wedge\space n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$:

- $$\text{a}-t=\frac{5\pi}{6}+2\pi n_1$$
- $$\text{a}-t=\frac{\pi}{6}+2\pi n_2$$

So, when we solve those for $t$:

- $$t=\text{a}-2\pi n_1-\frac{5\pi}{6}$$
- $$t=\text{a}-2\pi n_2-\frac{\pi}{6}$$